# Static getter-only property in class VS const

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have a base type and a couple of types derived from that base type. The base type has a property FriendlyName that contains information that is **constant** for every derived type (so not on a per-instance level, but on a type level)

How would I implement this? Right now, I have this (which *doesn't* do what I want)

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected static string friendlyName;

    public static string FriendlyName {
        get {
            return friendlyName;
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClassOne : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClassOne() {
        friendlyName = "A super duper derived class";
    }
}

public class DerivedClassTwo : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClassOne() {
        friendlyName = "Yet another derived class";
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do what I want? Or is this the way to do things or should I rather use a const string with the same name for every derived type?

**EDIT:**
To (hopefully) clear things up a bit. I have a MVC application. The class in question is the Model. In the view, I display a list of type `@model IEnumerable<BaseType>`. For every single item of the collection I want to show a descriptive text containing info about the current type, not just `typeof(item).ToString()` but a "friendly" description.

Comment: If it's constant for the derived type, I'd move the field to the derived types.  Otherwise I would expect to see collisions between the derived types.  You can mark the base class's property as `virtual` (I think) and override it in the derived classes.

Comment: The thing is I want to make sure that every derived class has a FriendlyName property, no matter what. Hence the idea to put it in the base class and set the value in the CTOR of the derived class.

Comment: Which is why I suggested marking the base class property as `virtual`.  It's just a guess, and I could be wrong.  It'd be very simple to test it out and see if it works though.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You're setting the static property in constructor. If no instance is created `friendlyName` will be null. You should simply add the property in respective classes

Comment: But STATIC does not have inheritance, so the property is not in the derived class at all.

Comment: Guys, don't focus on the code so much but rather on the idea behind it. That's why I asked in the first place.

Comment: Maybe make the base class abstract and the property abstract, so that the derived classes will need to implement it. 
But it will not work with static property though

Comment: Just ran a quick test.  First, using your approach both instances will have the last value assigned to to `FriendlyName`.  However, my idea won't work because you can't mark `static` with `virtual`.  You may not be able to do this with `abstract` and have to settle for instance properties.

Comment: Why would you need this property. What would it be used for and how? maybe that can bring a better answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel just edited the question

Comment: @lightxx See if my answer helps. and please avoid asking [XY questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm sorry. I thought stackoverflow encourages including attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: No, don't take me wrong please. You have to include your attempted solution anyways but you should talk about the actual problem. In your question you've never talked about it until we ask for it. As you can see how fast you got the answer once you explained your actual problem. :) So explaining the actual problem with the attempted solution is what brings you great answers in very short period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your edit. I'll simply create a custom attribute, or use existing on in .Net framework and decorate my class with the attibute.

```
[FriendlyName("Hey this is my cool class")]
public class DerivedClassOne : BaseClass 
{
...
}
```

and so forth for all the types.

Then use `Type.GetCustomAttributes` to read the attribute. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use static here. If your method is static it can be called even if there is no instance of the class. Also the value of the static method would be the last instance created (if none created - null). If you want to use static you should implement it for each of the derived types.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected readonly string friendlyName;

    public string FriendlyName {
        get {
            return friendlyName;
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClassOne : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClassOne() {
        friendlyName = "A super duper derived class";
    }
}

public class DerivedClassTwo : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClassOne() {
        friendlyName = "Yet another derived class";
    }
}
```